# Running a singular application on startup, fullscreened

Tags: startup, application, kiosk, fullscreen, vulkan

I want to run a single application, specifically a Vulkan game, on Linux. I kind of want it to be like a kiosk, but not just for displaying information. The operating system's one use for me is to run this application.
 How exactly do I do this? I am new to Linux, so I don't know much about how to work with it.

Comment: Is this for ease of use only or is security a concern (read: do you expect users to actively circumvent the kiosk mode)?

Comment: I don't care too much for security, though a secure solution would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but from the CLI you can do this to run Firefox for example in X:

```
xinit firefox $* -- :0 vt$XDG_VTNR
```

This will fire up Firefox in X and IIRC exit to the terminal on exit.  If your application can quit and this is not desired behavior, you can script it to reload on exit, and be the only thing the user can do on login, etc.